# FabricJS Right to Left Text Direction

Tags: javascript, canvas, right-to-left, fabricjs

I am trying to use Hebrew which is a "right to left" language, the "default l"left to right" setting messes up all the punctuation.  Any ideas about how to change from "left to right" to "right to left" in the fabricJS text element?

Comment: We don't support RTL text at the moment. Perhaps you can just reverse text string before creating a `fabric.Text` out of it?

Comment: isn't it possible to use original element's style property ?

Comment: @kangax, thank you for your reply.  The problem with reversing the text direction is that I am using Hebrew with diacritic characters which go in the direction of the language.  Is there perhaps another work around?  Or perhaps a file I can edit to allow RTL? And do you think RTL will have support soon?

Comment: RTL support is honestly low-priority, there's so many other things we have on a near-future roadmap. Unless someone else contributes it. If the letters go in a different direction, shouldn't horizontal flipping help?

Comment: @kangax any update on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add RTL to your canvas, this will solve your problem.
Using fabric, you have 2 canvas elements so:

for the visual part:
Try this:

```
<canvas dir="rtl" ></canvas>
```

And if you want to create an image from this canvas, add RTL to the upper canvas:

```
$(".upper-canvas").css("direction","rtl");
```

I'm using Hebrew and it works perfectly, maybe someone can add this to the source code.

Comment: It just didn't work work me. I'm using Fabric JS 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'textAlign' attribute and set it to right

e.g.

```
var text = 'this is\na multiline\ntext\naligned right!';
var alignedRightText = new fabric.Text(text, {
  textAlign: 'right'
});
```

Comment: text alignment and direction are two different concepts.
Alignment determines where the whole line resides. to the left, or to the right. it defines the borders of the LINE.
but direction determines if WORDS IN THE LINE get sorted from right, or left. this means, if direction property is set to the right, then curser is always at rightmost end.

Answer (score 0):

Those of you who are still looking for an answer. Downgrade to version 4.6.0 and use `textAlign:center` and `direction:rtl` on a text object.